# Wordpress Theme that returns all posts as a JSON object?

Tags: theme-development

Are there any Wordpress themes that will just return a JSON object that can be processed by Javascript to display a list of postings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/) plugin does.